# Page Exit Alert Message not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have my JavaScript alert on a page which alerts user with my custom message.

> About my script, when a user try to exit or refresh a page they get alert with my custom message
> **"Please Stay on this page to avail discount"**
> When they choose to stay they are redirected to
> **discount_offer.html**

**MY SCRIPT:**

```
<script language="javascript">
    var vals=0;
    function displayMsg() {
        window.onbeforeunload = function evens(evt) {}
            window.location.href = 'discount_offer.html';
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = function evens(evt) {
    var message = 'Please Stay on this page to avail discount';
      if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
          evt = window.event;
      }
        timedCount();
        vals++;
      if (evt) {
          evt.returnValue = message ;
          return message ;
      }
      trace(evt);
    }
    function timedCount()
    {
        t=setTimeout("timedCount()",100);
        if(vals>0)
        {
            displayMsg();
            clearTimeout(t);
        }
    }
    </script>
    
<p> <h1> My page Content here! </h1> </p>
```

***>> PROBLEM:***

My script works perfectly in Chrome, but it does not show my Custom Message in Firefox. Instead, it shows a Firefox default message:

> "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved"

***>> My Question Is:***

How can I get rid of this default Firefox message and show my message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way you can change it:

In FF 4 and later the returned string is not displayed to the user, as per this [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292).

An alternative solution would be to highlight unsaved fields and/or put a message somewhere on the page.

Comment: Excellent Information! Never thought about this that problem is in Firefox Version and not in my script. Very useful info for some one with similar requirement and struggling to get this.. Thank you Kiro!